# Cannot use SQLAlchemy Session() outside Flask application context for unit testing

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, python-unittest

This is my inside `flaskapp/__init__.py` for creating my Flask app, with it I can access Session inside any module in the package, by just importing Session from `flaskapp/db.py`:

```py
import os
from flask import Flask

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY=b'some_secret_key',
        DEBUG=True,
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI=f'sqlite:///{os.path.join(app.instance_path, "flaskapp.sqlite")}',
    )

    if test_config is None:
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass

    with app.app_context():
        from flaskapp.routes import home, auth

        from flaskapp.db import init_db
        init_db()

    return app
```

This is my `flaskapp/db.py`:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from flask import current_app

engine = create_engine(current_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'], echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def init_db():
    import flaskapp.models as models
    models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def drop_db():
    import flaskapp.models as models
    models.Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

With that, I can access the database in any other module, for example, `flaskapp/auth.py`:

```py
from flask import flash, session
from sqlalchemy import select

from flaskapp.db import Session
from flaskapp.models import User

def log_user(username: str, password: str) -> bool:
    with Session() as db_session:
        stmt1 = select(User).where(User.username == username)
        query_user = db_session.execute(stmt1).first()

        if not query_user:
            flash('Some error message')

        # Some password verifications and other things
        session['username'] = query_user[0].username
        flash('Successfully logged in')

        return True
```

Until that point, I don't have any problem, the problem comes when I try to do unit testing with `unittest`, I can't set the test environment and I don't know how can I use the `Session` object defined in `flaskapp/db.py` for testing in a separate database. Everything I've tried until now gets me an error, this is my `tests/__init__.py`:

```py
import unittest

from flaskapp import create_app
from flaskapp.db import Session
from flaskapp.models import User

class BaseTestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app(test_config={
            'TESTING': True,
            'DEBUG': True,
            'APP_ENV': 'testing',
             # I pass the test database URI expecting the engine to use it
            'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'sqlite:///testdb.sqlite',
        })
        self.client = self.app.test_client()

        # Context
        with self.app.app_context():
            self.populate_db()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def populate_db(self):
        with Session() as db_session:
            db_session.add(User(
                username='Harry',
                email='harry@yahoo.es',
                password = 'Harry123.'
            ))

            db_session.commit()
```

When I try to use the Session object inside `populate_db()` I get this error:

```bash
=====================================================================
ERROR: tests.test_auth (unittest.loader._FailedTest.tests.test_auth)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests.test_auth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 407, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/unittest/loader.py", line 350, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/chus/usb/soft/proy/SAGC/tests/test_auth.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flaskapp.db import Session
  File "/home/chus/usb/soft/proy/SAGC/flaskapp/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(current_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'], echo=True)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/chus/usb/soft/proy/SAGC/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 316, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[misc]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/chus/usb/soft/proy/SAGC/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Can someone help me out? I've tried everything to make the tests use the app context in order to populate the test database and make queries but it appears to be conflicting with it being created in `create_app()` or something.

Answer (score 0):

Firsly, the error you posted is about `tests/test_auth.py` which you did not include.

However, your code is tightly coupling the flask app and the `db.py` module with the use of `flask.current_app` to obtain the engine url.

So the engine creation will only work if there is an app context, which is probably absent when you do a top level import (line 1) of `from flaskapp.db import Session` in `tests/test_auth.py`.

A solution could be creating the engine and sessionmaker (or scoped_session) with your `create_app` and injecting the engine or Session in your functions (look up [dependency injection principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)):

```py
def init_db(engine):
    models.Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def drop_db(engine):
    models.Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

```py
def log_user(session, username: str, password: str) -> bool:
    stmt1 = select(User).where(User.username == username)
    query_user = session.execute(stmt1).first()
    # skipping the rest
```

Or look into [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/).